# How to access GitHub variables from a custom action's dockerfile?

Tags: github, dockerfile, github-actions

I have this workflow yaml file:

```yaml
name: PHP code review

on: push

jobs:
  phpunit:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: PHPUnit
      uses: ./.github/actions/phpunit
```

This is the `.github/actions/phpunit/action.yml` file:

```yaml
name: PHPUnit in Docker
description: Run PHPUnit in a custom configured Docker container

runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: phpunit.dockerfile
```

And this is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

# Update aptitude with new repo
RUN apt-get update

# Install software 
RUN apt-get install -y git

# Clone the conf files into the docker container
RUN git clone https://${{ secrets.PHPUNIT_ACCESS_TOKEN }}@github.com/${{ GITHUB_REPOSITORY }}
```

But in the Dockerfile it looks like a string, and not a variable.

How can I access to GitHub variables in my Dockerfile?

Comment: Maybe try passing it as build argument? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

Comment: Are you sure you want to clone the repository in the dockerfile? How about mapping a volume? You seem to already have the repository checked out.

Comment: @frennky I tried it and also not worked.

Comment: @rethab it's a workaround becuse of I didn't was abel to copy files & folders into docker container or use as volume. The reason was the `action.yml` file is in `.github/actions/phpunit/` folder and the dockerfile is there too. And because of this structure, the Docker can't see upper directories, so can't access to the project files. And I don't want to move to upper directory for avoid confusing files in the project root folder.

Comment: Why do you create an action just to "run" the Dockerfile? If the action is really needed, couldn't the action be a composite action that first checks out the repository?

Comment: @rethab if you check my example codes I use `uses: actions/checkout@v2`. And the reason is for creating an action is to be easier to maintain, easier to use and make it reuseable.

Comment: @rethab of course there is some more custom codes what I want to use in the dockerfile & several parameters what I want to use inside of docker.

Comment: What I meant with the checkout is not in the workflow, but inside the action. From what I can see your action only does a `using: docker`. What I meant was to create a [composite run steps action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action).

Comment: @rethab anyway, I can't access GitHub variables in the dockerfile nor the action input parameters